# Added reference to .lib project - project not using .cpp file?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, reference, static-libraries

I am still reasonably new to C++ so forgive me if I have misunderstood something.

I have a C++ library that contains sql connection classes, and I want to use it in a project. I have:

- Added it to the same solution
- Added a reference to it in "Framework and References"
- Included in the library's header file in stdafx.cpp of the main project
- Added the library project's directory as an include directory to the main project

But when compiling the project I am still getting a number of `unresolved external symbol` errors.

**If I include the library project's *.cpp file it works fine**, but I didn't think you would have to do this.

---

These are the exact errors I am getting:

```
2>Link:
2>  sqlConnector.obj : MSIL .netmodule or module compiled with /GL found; restarting link with /LTCG; add /LTCG to the link command line to improve linker performance
2>     Creating library .\Release\MainProject.lib and object .\Release\MainProject.exp
2>LINK : warning LNK4098: defaultlib 'mfc100u.lib' conflicts with use of other libs; use /NODEFAULTLIB:library
2>LINK : warning LNK4098: defaultlib 'mfcs100u.lib' conflicts with use of other libs; use /NODEFAULTLIB:library
2>MainProject.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: bool __thiscall SQLQuery::AddParameter(class ATL::CStringT<char,class StrTraitMFC_DLL<char,class ATL::ChTraitsCRT<char> > >)" (?AddParameter@SQLQuery@@QAE_NV?$CStringT@DV?$StrTraitMFC_DLL@DV?$ChTraitsCRT@D@ATL@@@@@ATL@@@Z)
2>MainProject.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: void __thiscall SQLQuery::SetQuery(class ATL::CStringT<char,class StrTraitMFC_DLL<char,class ATL::ChTraitsCRT<char> > >)" (?SetQuery@SQLQuery@@QAEXV?$CStringT@DV?$StrTraitMFC_DLL@DV?$ChTraitsCRT@D@ATL@@@@@ATL@@@Z)
2>MainProject.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: bool __thiscall SQLQuery::Open(class ATL::CStringT<char,class StrTraitMFC_DLL<char,class ATL::ChTraitsCRT<char> > >)" (?Open@SQLQuery@@QAE_NV?$CStringT@DV?$StrTraitMFC_DLL@DV?$ChTraitsCRT@D@ATL@@@@@ATL@@@Z)
2>MainProject.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: void __thiscall SQLQuery::SetConnectionString(class ATL::CStringT<char,class StrTraitMFC_DLL<char,class ATL::ChTraitsCRT<char> > >)" (?SetConnectionString@SQLQuery@@QAEXV?$CStringT@DV?$StrTraitMFC_DLL@DV?$ChTraitsCRT@D@ATL@@@@@ATL@@@Z)
2>sqlConnector.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: void __thiscall CAMTrace::SetEXEName(wchar_t const *)" (?SetEXEName@CAMTrace@@QAEXPB_W@Z)
2>sqlConnector.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: void __thiscall CAMTrace::Trace(wchar_t const *,int,int)" (?Trace@CAMTrace@@QAEXPB_WHH@Z)
2>.\Release\MainProject.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 6 unresolved externals
```

Answer (score 1):

what u need to do is add the libraries binary (the *.lib) file to the linker inputs of your project.

In order to do this u need to specify where to look for the file which is an entry under

***Linker/General/Additional Library Directories***

and after that u add the library to the Linker inputs under

***Linker/Input/Additional Dependencies***

Comment: Thanks for the response but I've done that and am still getting the same errors... does it matter that I have moved the lib from the release folder to a common folder where lots of lib files are held?

Comment: no, as long as the common folder is added to the project as well. the error message you get indicates that the symbols needed are not found. Are u sure that the library contains them?

Comment: Sorry to be a nuisance - how would I check that exactly? The library project compiles fine, and like I say if I include the .cpp file it all works.

Comment: see dumpbin.exe - a microsoft tool to look for symbols within a given lib. that it works with the original source code within your project is clear since the linker doesnt need the library for those symbols anymore - they are in your project by then.

Comment: I'm trying to use dumpbin but I have no idea what I'm looking at.. using the /symbols flag just returns "File Type: LIBRARY" - is that an issue? My concern with the .cpp include is that if they are all correctly in the .cpp why would they not be in the .lib?